# Algebraic Calculation of Wiener Process

Tags: wiener

What is the meaning of "Wiener Process does not support algebraic calculation hence we focused on it's increment"

Comment: Hi: Brownian motion increments are iid normal. The Brownian motion  process itself is a stochastic integral so much more complicated. Not sure if that's what yiou're looking for.

Comment: Understanding Wiener Processes required important mathematical advances by N. Wiener and K. Ito (the invention of a new calculus based on the symbol $dZ$ "the increment of the Wiener proces"). Could the same results have been derived using simple algebra?  It would be absurd IMHO...